# Issue connecting from android app to server?

Tags: php, android, wamp

I have created an activity to test connecting from my App to WAMP server. However currently it doesnt seem to work.

The activity should change the textbox on screen once it connects to the server and the button is clicked. However currently it doesn't change.

Are there are errors in the code below? Note: I cannot see any errors in Logcat and the Server logs do not show a connection.

Server class:

```
 public class Server {

        // Declared Constants
        public static final String SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.56.1/androidtest.php"; //need to change?

        /**
         * Gets the bit of text to set
         * @return A string containing the text to set
         */
        public static String getTextToSet() {
                /*
                 * Let's construct the query string. It should be a key/value pair. In
                 * this case, we just need to specify the command, so no additional
                 * arguments are needed.
                 */
                String data = "command=" + URLEncoder.encode("getTextToSet");
                return executeHttpRequest(data);
        }

        /**
         * Helper function used to communicate with the server by sending/receiving
         * POST commands.
         * @param data String representing the command and (possibly) arguments.
         * @return String response from the server.
         */
        private static String executeHttpRequest(String data) {
                String result = "";
                try {
                        URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
                        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();


                        /*
                         * We need to make sure we specify that we want to provide input and
                         * get output from this connection. We also want to disable caching,
                         * so that we get the most up-to-date result. And, we need to 
                         * specify the correct content type for our data.
                         */
                        connection.setDoInput(true);
                        connection.setDoOutput(true);
                        connection.setUseCaches(false);
                        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        //connection.setRequestProperty("Content -Type", "textback.php");
                        //connection.setRequestProperty("Value1", "Value2");

                        // Send the POST data
                        DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                        dataOut.writeBytes(data);
                        dataOut.flush();
                        dataOut.close();

                        // get the response from the server and store it in result
                        DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); 
                        String inputLine;
                        while ((inputLine = dataIn.readLine()) != null) {
                                result += inputLine;
                        }
                        dataIn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        /*
                         * In case of an error, we're going to return a null String. This
                         * can be changed to a specific error message format if the client
                         * wants to do some error handling. For our simple app, we're just
                         * going to use the null to communicate a general error in
                         * retrieving the data.
                         */
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        result = null;
                }

                return result;
        }
    }
```

Connect to Server class:

```
public class ConnectToServer extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.connecttoserver);

        final String textToSetAs = null;
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_to_set);

        // Call the task to set the text on screen
        Button setText = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_to_set_text);
        setText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                (new GetTextTask()).execute();

            }
        });
    }

    /**
//   * Used to spawn a thread to retrieve the animal sound?
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private class GetTextTask extends AsyncTask {

        /**
         * Let's make the http request and return the result as a String.
         */
        protected String doInBackground(Object... args) {

            // Return the server call to get the text to set
            return Server.getTextToSet();

        }

        /**
         * Display the result as a Toast.
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(Object objResult) {
            // check to make sure we're dealing with a string
            /*
             * if (objResult != null && objResult instanceof String) { String
             * result = (String) objResult;
             * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
             * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
             */

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_to_set);
            tv.setText((CharSequence) objResult);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

PHP script:

```
<?php

  echo "Did it work?";
  // get the command
  $command = $_REQUEST['command'];

  // determine which command will be run
  if($command == "getTextToSet") {
    // return the text to set
    echo "This is what you wanted back?";
  } else {
        echo "";
  }

?>
```

Comment: Why don't you try to debug, either with debugger, or simply with `Log.d(..)`? Check if AsyncTask `doInBackground` is reached, then check if result is returned to `onPostExecute`. Check the exact response from server in `executeHttpRequest`. Also, check if IP is correct, and your device is connected to correct wi-fi. For emulator, you may try `localhost`, though no guarantees there.

Comment: Have you tried pasting your url into a browser to test the connection?

Comment: yes I am able to populate MySQL database using a PHP script but I cant seem to get any connectivity with the android app!?

Comment: I believe you are saying that you can run a PHP script on your server and get a correct result.  That doesn't mean that your URL is correct.  A simple test would be to paste the URL into the address bar of a browser.  You should see "Did it work?"  If not then the URL is incorrect.

Comment: Yes whenever I run the PHP script in my browser I do see the message "did it work", Does this mean that the error is with the android app? Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the line

```
 uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

in your manifest file?

Comment: Yes I do. I am not sure what the problem can be it is very fustrating!